# How is this representation defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, definition, lie-algebras

Given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with a representation $V$, how do we define the representation  $\bigwedge^n\text{Sym}^m(V) $?

Comment: Well, first we apply the $\operatorname{Sym}^m$ construction, then we apply the $\bigwedge^n$ construction. Do you understand either of those steps yet, or are they both mysterious?

Comment: Look up "plethysm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spiritually (and, one can prove, concretely as well) representations of lie algebras are obtained from differentiating representations of Lie groups.

If $G$ acts on $V$ then the action on $\mathrm{Sym}^mV$ is given by $g(v_1v_2\cdots v_m)=(gv_1)(gv_2)\cdots(gv_m)$, and the action on $\Lambda^nV$ is given by $g(v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n)=(gv_1)\wedge(gv_2)\wedge\cdots\wedge(gv_n)$. Since the multiplication in the symmetric and exterior algebras are linear, we can differentiate these (with $g=\exp(tX)$ at $t=0$) by using the product rule, in which case we get

$$ X(v_1v_2\cdots v_m)=\big[(Xv_1)v_2\cdots v_m\big]+\big[v_1(Xv_2)\cdots v_m\big]+\cdots+\big[v_1v_2\cdots(Xv_m)\big] $$

and similarly for $X(v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n)$. Of course, things get a little complicated when you're doing the $\Lambda^n$ *of* the $\mathrm{Sym}^m$, but again you're just using the product rule, this time viewing both symmetric and exterior products and products that the product rule applies to.